# cURL set Accept-Language not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make a cURL request. The problem I am facing is that the page have different text depending on which country it is. So I would like the cURL request to have the language en_US (English). So it will get the English text on the website.

Currently I have this code, but its not getting the US text.

```
$url = 'http://testurl.com'; // Not the real URL
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array("Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"),
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15"),
);

$ch      = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$err     = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg  = curl_error($ch);
$header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo htmlspecialchars($content);
```

So to make this simple, I would like the cURL request to send the request with the US language, if possible.

---

Right now it has the language 'dutch' I think this is because my hosting server is located in Netherlands. So therefore it is deutch. But I would like to change it to English.

Comment: Paste your code here instead of hyperlinking it to someother site.

Comment: Sorry, but every time i paste it here it says there is a error.. :/

Comment: Weird O.o ...Also, the pastebin link is not working for me.

Comment: Can this even be done?